# Show pyfolio output on view (html) in Flask application

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to display pyfolio `pf.create_full_tear_sheet()` output into my Flask html view similar to what [jupyter/notebook](https://jupyter.org/) does.

I was able to use `pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(...,return_fig=True)` to save image and show that image on view like below:

```
f = pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(returns=returns, positions=positions, transactions=tran,benchmark_rets=benchmark_returns,return_fig=True);
f.savefig('returns.png')
```

How can I achieve the same for **create_full_tear_sheet()** method?